# Extract/Display SQL from crystal report

Tags: java, crystal-reports, sybase, fileparsing

**Problem:**

I have a crystal report file on a computer. I need to know how the crystal report queries a database.

**Background:**

The crystal report file was created 10+ years ago by a highly paid contractor. No one knows anything about how it was created. We do not have any crystal report authoring software. We don't have any information related to the crystal report file, just the report file.

**Question:**

If I have a crystal report file here: `/file/path/to/myMagicReport.rpt`, how can I extract the SQL string used to query the database from the file?

*Ideally I would not like to install any software, just extract the information programatically.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to programatically extract the SQL query. Unfortunately you will have to either have somebody do it for you or install a version of Crystal Reports. 
There is a free trial for Crystal Reports available from SAP [here](https://global.sap.com/campaign/ne/free_trial/crystal_reports_2013/index.epx?kNtBzmUK9zU). I would download it, open the report. You can find the SQL query under the Database tab. Please see screenshot.[image: SQL query from report]

EDIT:

There is also rpt inspector, which will allow you to get the SQL query. They have a free trial as well [here](http://www.softwareforces.com/Products/rpt-inspector-professional-suite-for-crystal-reports). It may give you all the info you need but probably won't let you make any changes to the report layout, if that's something you had in mind.